# What is a 'data moment'?

Tags: moments

I know a moment of a random variable is the expected value of the random variable raised to a given power (possibly with the mean subtracted).

I was reading a paper published in Econometrica in which they speak of 'data moments' such as 'job creation rate', 'job destruction rate' and 'standard deviation of log employment across firms', among others.

Is this term ('data moments') a statistical term? Does it have any statistical/mathematical meaning?

Citation:Econometrica, Vol. 87, No. 5 (September, 2019), 1507–1541
"How Destructive Is Innovation?" by Macia, Hsieh and  Klenow

Comment: Search our site: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=data+moment .  Perhaps a little harder to find will be posts that point out that the data moments are precisely those of their empirical distributions.

Comment: Please share a citation, otherwise it is hard to comment. There are [moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)) in statistics.

Comment: For those of you in the US old enough to remember, here are images of (presidential candidate) [Ross Perot having a data moment](https://www.google.com/search?q=ross+perot+charts).

Comment: In Perot's case a 'data moment' may well be homeomorphic to a senior moment. Answering such questions is beyond the scope of the present work, but is an interesting topic of future research.